# Copy value from another column based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I have two worksheets in google sheets.

In Sheet1 I have a list of items along with a type column.

In Sheet2 I have a list of unique items taken from sheet1, I manually enter the type for each item over here.

What I want is to populate the type column in Sheet1 automatically from Sheet2 based on item name. Something like

> =IF(Sheet1!B2 = Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!B1)

but this formula only checks a single value and not a range of values

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MAneHwmJ6SN_p5VwyQ1myibigRXKpd_Mfev9A89d05M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling I found that this works

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$6,2,false)
```